# Unable to copy files / folders in /dev/sda partitions

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, fedora-25

[image: Partition Details]I have recently installed linux 18.04 on my machine. previously I had installed windows & created 4 partitions that is C,D,E,F.
I have installed linux on C drive. other 3 partitions are displaying as /dev/sda5, /dev/sda6, /dev/sda7.

Now I want to copy something in that partitions I am unable to do any operations. I tried to change permission of the partitions but it is throwing error

> chmod: changing permissions of '/media/lucky/others': Read-only file system

I also re-mount the partitions but nothing happen.

Comment: Which file system were you using in windows ? May be due to different file system you are not able to access. Could you share output of #lsblk -f command so it will easy to find solutions.

Comment: can you please share output of `sudo fsck -Af -M`

Comment: sudo fsck -Af -M

O/P:-
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1

Comment: @Shivani please check attached the screenshot

Comment: solved the issue "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda7"